# Average of a vector field over a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose we have a vector field $\mathbf{E}$ and a surface $S$. What is the formula for the average of $\mathbf{E}$ over the surface?

**My attempt:**

I think it is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{area(S)}}\oint_S\mathbf{E}da$ where $da$ is the infinitesimal area element, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: This looks right to me.

Comment: Your expression is correct.